# Conditional expectation two random variable

Tags: time-series, self-study, covariance, conditional-expectation

[image]

It says to use Law of Iterated Expectations, but I don't know how to solve this. Can someone please help me with this question?

Comment: You may get better answers if you show what sort of start you have made even if you think it is wrong then someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: You need to follow https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info. Why the time-series tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the formula $$ Cov[X,Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]  $$

Compute $$ E[XY] = E[E[XY | X]] = E[X *E[Y|X]] = E[X  * (a+bX)] = E[aX + bX^2] $$

$$E[aX+bX^2] = a *E[X] + b * E[X^2]$$

as well as

$$E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]] = E[a+ bX] = a + b *E[X]$$

Subsitute into the formula for covariance, and we find:

$$ Cov[X,Y] = a * E[X] + b * E[X^2] - E[X] * (a+b*E[X])$$
$$ Cov[X,Y] = a * E[X] + b *E[X^2] -a *E[X] -b *E[X]^2$$

$$ Cov[X,Y] = b*E[X^2] -b * E[X]^2 $$
$$ Cov[X,Y] = b * (E[X^2] - E[X]^2) $$
$$ b = \frac{Cov[X,Y]}{Var[X]} $$

since

$$Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$

Comment: Please don't give full answers to self-study questions