# Conditional expectation and Covariance

Tags: self-study, covariance, conditional-expectation

[image]

Is this because when X and Y are independent, E(XY) = E(X)E(Y).

So Cov(X,Y)= E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=0?

Or is there another way of solving this through using Law of Iterated Expectations?

Comment: Why doesn't the [answer to your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306476/conditional-expectation-two-random-variable) address this one, too?  After all, it's a generalization of this one with $b=0$.  Is it really necessary to re-ask it?

Answer (score 1):

$Cov[X,Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$

$E[XY] = E[E[XY|X]] = E[X * E[Y|X]]= E[X * E[Y]] = E[Y] * E[X] $
 since  $$ E[Y]$$  is a constant in the expression $$ E[X *E[Y]]$$.

Hope this helps.